# Getting Segmentation fault while loading OBJ file

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, glm-math, wavefront

I am getting 'Segmentation fault(core dumped)' in C++ using gcc after adding this piece of code to my OpenGL program

```
vector<GLfloat> vecTofloat(vector<glm::vec3> veca){
    vector<GLfloat> fa;
    for (int i = 0; i < veca.size(); i++){
        glm::vec3 vec = veca[i];
        fa.push_back(vec.x);
        fa.push_back(vec.y);
        fa.push_back(vec.z);
    }
    return fa;
}

vector<GLfloat> vecTofloat(vector<glm::vec2> veca){
    vector<GLfloat> fa;
    for (int i = 0; i < veca.size(); i++){
        glm::vec2 vec = veca[i];
        fa.push_back(vec.x);
        fa.push_back(vec.y);
    }
    return fa;
}

MeshInstance loadOBJ(const char* path, const char* texPath, int tw, int th){
    vector<glm::vec3> vert;
    vector<glm::vec3> tvert;
    vector<GLuint> ivert;
    vector<glm::vec3> norm;
    vector<glm::vec3> tnorm;
    vector<GLuint> inorm;
    vector<glm::vec2> tex;
    vector<glm::vec2> ttex;
    vector<GLuint> itex;

    FILE* file = fopen(path, "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        LOG_ERROR("Unable to load OBJ mesh.");
        exit(-1);
    }

    while(true){
        char start[128];

        int res = fscanf(file, "%s", start);

        if (res == EOF){
            break;
        } else if (strncmp(start, "v", strlen("v")) == 0){
            glm::vec3 vertex;
            fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z);
            tvert.push_back(vertex);
        } else if (strncmp(start, "vt", strlen("vt")) == 0){
            glm::vec2 tex;
            fscanf(file, "%f %f\n", &tex.x, &tex.y);
            ttex.push_back(tex);
        } else if (strncmp(start, "vn", strlen("vn")) == 0){
            glm::vec3 nrm;
            fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &nrm.x, &nrm.y, &nrm.z);
            tnorm.push_back(nrm);
        } else if (strncmp(start, "f", strlen("f")) == 0){
            std::string vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
            unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
            fscanf(file, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n",&vertexIndex[0],&uvIndex[0],&normalIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2] );

            ivert.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
            ivert.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
            ivert.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
            itex.push_back(uvIndex[0]);
            itex.push_back(uvIndex[1]);
            itex.push_back(uvIndex[2]);
            inorm.push_back(normalIndex[0]);
            inorm.push_back(normalIndex[1]);
            inorm.push_back(normalIndex[2]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ivert.size(); i+=3){
        unsigned int vertex = ivert[i];
        vert.push_back(tvert[vertex - 1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < itex.size(); i+=3){
        unsigned int vertex = itex[i];
        tex.push_back(ttex[vertex - 1]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < inorm.size(); i+=3){
        unsigned int vertex = inorm[i];
        norm.push_back(tnorm[vertex - 1]);     
    }

    return LoadToVAO(vecTofloat(vert), ivert, vecTofloat(tex), texPath, tw, th);
}
```

What it does is simply load an obj file. I know it is due to accessing memory that is already removed but I am not able to figure out where the segmentation fault is occuring in the program.

Edit:
I debugged the program with gdb and now I get this:

```
Starting program: /home/saroj/workspace/Rachaita3D/Rachaita3D step
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7ffff5120700 (LWP 11819)]

Thread 1 "Rachaita3D" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555565f66 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0> >::construct<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0> const&> (this=0x7fffffffdca0, __p=0x555555950a50, __args#0=...)                              
    at /usr/include/c++/8/ext/new_allocator.h:136
136             { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Edit 2: 
    At `tex.push_back(ttex[vertex - 1]);` , p ttex[vertex - 1] returns

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
```

For some reason my loader is not loading texture coordinates and normal vectors.

Comment: I see some potential causes for undefined behavior here, due lack of bounds checking, but nothing that's provably wrong. It's just as likely that there's a bug resulting in memory corruption somewhere else in the existing code that was not detected until the change in behavior that results from adding this new code. You will need to use static analysis tools and/or your debugger in order to debug this. Loading the coredump into your debugger may offer some clues.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I updated the post with the gdb log.

Comment: You can get much more information from gdb, then that. Such as a backtrace, and the values of all variables that are at each stack frame's call site. Sounds like you need to spend a little bit more time learning how to get useful information out of gdb, in order to be able to debug complicated C++ code.

Comment: Edit 2 might help cause I can't get why ttex[vertex - 1] is at 0x0.

Comment: Type "bt" (and press enter) in gdb to get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the issue is in the way you're parsing the Wavefront OBJ commands.

The first check `strncmp(start, "v", strlen("v"))` does not check if the command was `v`, it checks if the command *starts* with "v".

When code encounters `vn` or `vt`, the first check will find 'v' at the beginning, and wrong branch is taken. You fill up the `tvert` array with unrelated data, leaving `tnorm` and `ttex` empty, so the code crashes trying to index those.

Either compare strings with `strcmp()`, or reorder the checks, so the `v` will be tested last.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing something wrong about the data. Did you go through the [Wavefront OBJ specification](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~boulos/cs3505/obj_spec.pdf)?

Your code expects very exact structure from the actual 3D model being loaded, while the OBJ format allow quite flexible combinations of faces' elements.

OBJ file can support not only triangles, but also polygons (all flat) made of 4 and more vertices. You shouldn't hardcode number 3 anywhere, but maybe you could skip/ignore 'lines' made of 2 vertices.

The data vectors size may differ from 3. Typically, vertex coordinates are 2-component, not 3, though sometimes you will see 3, or even 4 components.

Each face specify its vertices' components indices, with indices in `f` command given in multiple variants - as a single number, specifying only the position. As a pair of indices delimited by `/` slash, specifying position and texture coordinate. As a triplet of indices, specifying position/texture_coords/normal_vector. When a model has position and normals data without texture coordinates, then you'll see a triplet with texture coords missing entirely, like `1//2`. You have to track these differences, because some data will miss entirely, and indexing it will trigger the segfault.

Another feature is in indices itself. They could be negative, specifying not the position in the data array, but an offset from the current position in the accumulated array of components' vectors.

So your code has at least two problems that will definitely cause the segfault, depending on the exact 3D file being loaded.

1. You don't check if vertex component index (texture coordinate or normal) is present in the `f` command, so reading that index will fail, giving either garbage, or uninitialized zero. You will subtract 1 from that zero when doing `ttex[vertex - 1]`, and you're reading outside of the data array.
2. You don't check if the index was negative. So you will read outside of the data array again.

Comment: I am just trying to load a blender cube whose data is exactly what I am loading so this is not the case.

Comment: @SarojKr can you share that exact file?

Comment: Here's the link - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YNhzRKVivZ5AFD_k9FcNC1_RqrgRk_R_